# How could I position icon and text over my image responsively?

Tags: html, css

I know that I can use absolute position and change it through top, left and right, but the big problem is that it is not responsive in the image and when the pixel is changed, the icon comes out of the top of the image. Ex:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 70vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.item img {
  height: 20vw;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1-;
  filter: brightness(60%);
  object-fit: cover;
}

#item {
  font-size: 17vh;
}
```

```html
<div className='container'>
  <div className='item'>
    <img src={image1} alt="" />
    <MenuBookIcon id='item' />
    <h2>Item1</h2>
  </div>
  <div className='item'>
    <img src={image2} alt="" />
    <LocalCafeIcon id='item' />
    <h2>Item2</h2>
  </div>
  <div className='item'>
    <img src={image3} alt="" />
    <EmojiObjectsIcon id='item' />
    <h2>item3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your icons but, have you tried using display: flex on the .item?